# Is there a way to write the headers in the table in i18n format in vue3?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, internationalization, vuejs3, vue-i18n

I want to write headers name in the table in i18n format.I am using vue3 in my project. (and typescript of course).Thanks in advance!

Here is my html code

```
<Datatable
        :table-data="tableData"
        :table-header="tableHeader"
        :enable-items-per-page-dropdown="false"
        :loading="isTableLoading"
        :is-pagination="false"
        class="activity-table"
      >
      .
      .
      . </Datatable>
```

Here is my script code

```
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n/index";
const { t, te } = useI18n();
const tableHeader = ref([
  {
    name: "Username",
    key: "name",
    sortable: false,
  },
  {
    name: "Email",
    key: "email",
    sortable: false,
  },
  {
    name: "Phone",
    key: "phone",
    sortable: false,
  },
  .
  .
  . ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

As script code will execute before the component loads. Hence, It might be the case that `i18n` library will not be available at that time. Hence, What you can try is to translate the `tableHeader` object property in the component itself in the `mounted()` lifecycle hook.

**Example (In vue component) :**

```
mounted() {
  this.tableHeader.forEach((obj) => {
    obj.name = this.$t(obj.name)
  });
}
```